# How to get Onvif Media Profile Token on Python

Tags: python, onvif, python-onvif

I've been trying to request a Onvif Snapshot but the GetSnapshotUri() function takes a "Profile Token" as argument.

I've called the function GetProfiles() and it's result is a list of profiles and one of them has `a _token = "MediaProfile000"`.

If I just type this token in the GetSnapshotUri() function, it say's:

```
onvif.exceptions.ONVIFError: Unknown error: Method instance argument after ** must be a mapping, not str
```

So I tried this way:

```
profilesList = media.GetProfiles()
firstProfile = profilesList[0]
mediaProfileToken = firstProfile._token
media.GetSnapshotUri(mediaProfileToken)
```

But guess what?

```
onvif.exceptions.ONVIFError: Unknown error: Method instance argument after ** must be a mapping, not Text
```

Please Help

Comment: what is the library you are using?

Comment: Have you finally solve it? We try to do almost the same thing with no result =(

Answer (score 3):

```
profilesList = media.GetProfiles()
firstProfile = profilesList[0]
mediaProfileToken = firstProfile.token
media.GetSnapshotUri(mediaProfileToken)
```

this is worked for me!!
replacing firstProfile._token by firstProfile.token